# React-Native Android FCM: Didn't get a token

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-fcm

I am using **react-native-fcm** into my React-Native application. I am using below method to get device token for the push.

```
FCM.getFCMToken().then((token) => {
    alert('FCM Token: ' + token);
    console.log(token);           
});
```

The issue is, I am getting a token in iPhone application, but when I tried in Android, the method is not called.

I follow each and every step which is suggested by react-native-fcm. Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forget to initialize the Firebase from Android native side. I encounter with same issue. Below is the which help to solve the issue. Checkout my code:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
   try {
       FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
   }
 }
```

Just add  **FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);** into **onCreate()** method.

Cheers...

Comment: Got a device token from Android now. But Android device doesn't receive notification.  Do you have face any issue like this?